# Pathjs routing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-history, path.js

I have this route:

```
Path.map("/(:page_1)(/:page_2)/").to(funct);
```

and it is not matching

```
/projects/index2/
```

it matches `/anything` but not `/anything/anything`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping only the second optional value in parentheses. So, instead of doing:

```
Path.map("#/(:page_1)(/:page_2)/").to(funct);
```

try:

```
Path.map("#/:page_1(/:page_2)").to(funct);
```

Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jkeq9/1/